# In laptop with Windows 11 I can adjust screen brightness from Windows. In a desktop with Windows 11 I can't --- should I buy a new screen?

Tags: display, windows-11, brightness, hardware-rec

In laptop with Windows 11 I can adjust screen brightness from Windows but in a desktop with Windows 11 I can't.

This causes me to get an "eye pain" from a "brightness flash" if I wake up **at night** and then open the desktop screen.
Such "brightness flash" may last about 5 seconds if not about 7.5 seconds.
This brightness flash would still be felt even if I try to control the screen's brightness from buttons in the back of it (which isn't comfortable for me and takes more time than adjusting it from the operating system).
Before several years I shifted from working primarily from a desktop to primarily from a laptop and since then I have lost my habit to adjusting brightness from buttons of any desktop screen, to the habit of adjusting brightness from an operating system.
Recently I got back to work primarily from a desktop I can readjust myself to change brightness from a desktop screen but in my current screen it's not comfortable for me and anyway I prefer to do it from the operating system in general even in a desktop computer because from my experience it's just **faster** to do from an operating system thus reducing overall time of experiencing a "brightness flash" at night.

I can't understand why would either Microsoft and/or Screen manufacturers cause the problem of not letting a user adjust brightness from the operating system.
Will buying a new screen help and what should be a sole feature of such a screen to allow controlling its brightness from Windows 11?
I am not asking for a recommendation for any particular screen model or product, just to understand if the problem is in Windows, my current screen or both.

Comment: Why not control the desktop screen brightness with the on-monitor buttons meant for this?

Comment: @YisroelTech because that would still require me to turn on the screen and get a "brightness bomb" at night times and it's also much less comfortable than just dragging a button with the mouse quickly.

Comment: How would you drag the mouse in Windows without turning on the screen (and get the 'brightness bomb')?

Comment: @YisroelTech I meant that for a split of a second, I can handle that without problem but after that it's becoming a problem for me. I have edited to clarify.

Comment: Not really sure what your answer is. While I get the part of it being a tiny bit more convenient to click on your PC than pressing the monitor buttons (and I answered with software that might support that) I'm not really sure how it's quicker.

Comment: Though there are a few external displays (https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/adaptive-brightness-on-computer-monitors.3524614/) with adaptive brightness control (i.e., dimming when ambient lighting is low), you could implement yourself if you modify the backlight: https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/a-simple-implementation-of-lcd-brightness-control-using-the-max44009-ambientlight-sensor.html

Comment: I meant also that I am not used to change brightness from the buttons of this particular screen (and currently not any other screen) but what I am very used too from working years with laptop is controlling brightness from the operating system.

Comment: @YisroelTech I have edited the question for you that you would be sure that you understood me correctly without any doubt. Please go through my edit and tell me if now you think you fully understand me (I also edited for SEO reasons so this question would be easier to be found; I don't anyone to suffer from this problem).

Comment: Sounds very good 

Comment: Why don't you use software, e.g., [EasyMCC](https://bluesky-soft.com/en/EasyMCC.html)?

Comment: @Arctiic I never knew about it before. Please feel free to write an answer about it. You may want to include data on the difference between it and the two program's Yisroel Tech gave in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows built-in brightness slider doesn't support external monitors. [Microsoft recommends instead](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-screen-brightness-in-windows-3f67a2f2-5c65-ceca-778b-5858fc007041#:%7E:text=an%20external%20monitor.-,To%20change%20the%20brightness%20on%20an%20external%20monitor%2C%20use%20the,slider%20to%20adjust%20the%20brightness.) to use the buttons on the monitor to do it:

> You might not see the Brightness slider on desktop PCs that have an external monitor. To change the brightness on an external monitor, use the buttons on it.

You can try some 3rd party app that adds such functionality, like [**Monitorian**](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/monitorian/9NW33J738BL0?hl=en-us&gl=us&activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) or [**Twinkle Tray**](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/twinkle-tray-brightness-slider/9PLJWWSV01LK?hl=en-us&gl=us).

Another thing you may want to look into, is turning On Windows Night Light which should help the light be a bit less brutal.

Comment: I wonder why they use the word "may".

Comment: I have just tried both programs, both of them work great. The brightness adjusting is very slightly less "smooth" than in a laptop but it overall works fine and solves the problem for good. I misunderstand why Microsoft won't install similar native software in Windows as well. Isn't that a great user experience feature? Anyway thanks a lot for suggesting these software !

Comment: I also don't know about them (and good point with their "might") but it's possible just a result of the fact that in the past - quite some time ago... - not a lot of monitors supported the DDC/CI standard for sending/setting this via software (while internal displays always did since they didn't have another way to change it, lacking dedicated physical buttons.)

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a software solution, and it's open-source at that: [EasyMMC](https://bluesky-soft.com/en/EasyMCC.html)

Here is a description from the official page:

> **How to use**
> "Monitor" setting Select the monitor to be operated in a multi-monitor environment.  Also, when you turn on the "Sync" setting, the same operation will be performed simultaneously on all detected monitors.
>
> **Image Settings**
> Supports the following parameters.
>
> Luminance
> Contrast
> Saturation
> Hue
> Sharpness
> Gamma
> Color
> Temperature
>
> **Mode**
> Gain
> Black
> Level
> Audio Settings
>
> **Supports the following parameters**
> Speaker
> Volume
> Mute
>
> **Extra Settings**
> You can change manufacturer-specific settings.
>
> **Control**
> You can initialize monitor settings, change power mode and input source, save, and load presets and assign shortcut keys.
>
> **Supports the following power modes**
> DPMS On
> DPMS Standby
> DPMS Suspend
> DPMS Off
> Power Off
>
> **Supports the following input sources**
> Analog Video
> Digital Video (HDMI)
> Composite Video
> S-Video
> Turner
> Component Video
> DisplayPort
>
> **Information**
> Supports the following informations.
>
> Manufacturer ID
> Product Code
> Model Name
> Monitor Name
> Year of Manufacture
> Week of Manufacture
> Serial Number
> Controller Technology
> Type
> Sub-Pixel Layout
> Firmware Version
> Current Horizontal Frequency
> Current Vertical Frequency
> Current Usage Time

Remark: I have no idea why this software or class or software is so poorly known.  Despite having known about it directly myself, having to re-find the software was in itself challenging.